# Application_AcquireRequestState not executing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-asax

I have a old .net 3.5 mvc project I needed to do some changes to, I finally got it to build in visual studio 2013 but I have one last problem, I do my Language detection in the Application_AcquireRequestState method of the Global.asax file, but this method is not being executed.

I'm not sure what can be relevant so if more information is needed let me know.

other then that the project seems to work, but is just skipping this method, other methods such as Application_Start and RegisterRoutes are being executed.

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

---update----
I've put some code inside that illustrates that the method is not being executed at all

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var test = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        test++;
    }  
}
```

This has no effect on my application at all. I have a breakpoint at the var test = 1 and it is not working

Comment: Do you have any actual code inside this handler?

Comment: not being executed! can u elaborate a bit, any error message?

Comment: Global.aspx? Is it a typo or you put that into the wrong file?

Comment: I've updated my question. there is a lot of code inside but it is not being executed, I've added some code to illustrate this.

Comment: sorry yes this was a typo i've updated it: Global.asax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed visual studio 2010 and opened the project, no issues what so ever.

I still don't know why it was not working in Visual Studio 2013.

I always strive to use the latest technology in this case the new IDE but at some point it is just not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried turning of "Browser link"? I have had a couple of issues where request did different things then expected when this was turned on (it is on by default).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS Express or hooked up to the actual IIS on your machine, these events are being fired/processed outside of your code.  You cannot put a break point on them unless you use the Visual Studio Development Server. (Or attach to the IIS process that is actually running your code.)

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your answer, but I don't think this is the case, I don't think it is being executed at all because also if i add that infinite while loop nothing happens, also the code inside the method was in working order (I've executed the project in visual studio 2010 without problems), my setup is running with with normal iis express vs2013 combination. Also I can debug the code in vs2010